# Do I need "PreviewProvider" to use use @ObservedObject when building to a device SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink, observableobject

This is what my code is looking like:

```
import SwiftUI

struct dummy: View {
    var job: Job
    @ObservedObject var jobViewModel: JobViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Placeholder for job details, will not exists in production, please delete")
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            HStack{
                Text("Boat Name")
                    Spacer()
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                Text(job.boatName)
            }
        

            /*HStack{
                Text("Job Time")
                    Spacer()
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                Text(jobTime)
            }*/
            HStack{
                Text("Job Type")
                    Spacer()
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                Text(job.job)
            }
            HStack{
                Text("Owner's Name")
                Spacer()
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                Text(job.ownerName)
                //Text(job.time)
            }
            
            Button("Complete Job"){
                jobViewModel.complete(job)
            }.frame(width: 200)
        }
        
        
        
        
    }
}



/*struct dummy_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        dummy(job: Job[0])
    }
}*/
//foundout to get rid of this from below:
//https://medium.com/swift-productions/create-list-navigation-using-swiftui-c63534355fb1
//If i didn't get rid of it, it would case issues
```

If I keep out the "PreviewProvider" it works, If i keep it in, it throws errors. I am building directly to a device every time I try the app. Do I need this so the ObservedObject works?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the preview functionality, you'll have to provide some sort of instance for the `jobViewModel` parameter.

You haven't shown the code to `JobViewModel`, but it may be as simple as doing:

```
dummy(job: Job(), jobViewModel: JobViewModel())
```

*This is assuming Job and JobViewModel don't take any parameters -- if they do, you'll have to fill in values for those parameters as well. Xcode should be able to help you with autocomplete to show you what their parameters may be.*

Not having a preview will not affect your ability to run your app in non-preview mode on the simulator or a device.

Comment: I see you’re new to SO. If this answered your question, you can click the green check mark to accept the answer.